# Change the actionBar.newTab().setText() method lettters from uper case to lower?

Tags: android, xml

The `setText("Recents")` method by default Displays the Text in all caps `RECENTS` but in need to display them as `Recents`.

**I tried changing in styles but of no use can any one help me out!**

here is my code:

```
 ActionBar.Tab  recentsTab;
 recentsTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Recents");
```

styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own theme and set android : textAllCaps to false,
also change theme in your manifest file (android:theme="@style/MyTheme")....you can refer this code

```
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyTheme.MenuTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

<style name="MyTheme.MenuTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
```